# Is Kotlin targeting the JVM when programming for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm fairly new to Kotlin and I noticed that the API docs tend to have differing support for the major Kotlin platform targets JVM, JS, and Native (I'm asssuming Common means it should be supported the same everywhere).  My use case for Kotlin is Android development, but so far I haven't found a definitive answer as to what platform target compatibility building for Android implies.  Presumably it would be JVM since kotlinc does compile Java bytecode as the first step in and Android build, but that's confusing and unintuitive since Android has nothing to do with the JVM itself.  In the [Kotlin FAQs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/faq.html#what-is-kotlin) describing what Kotlin is, they mention Android as a target platform; however, Android is not listed in the Platforms heading of their documentation (only JVM, JS, Native, and Scripting).

Is Kotlin targeting the JVM with respect to its API when programming for Android?  If not, what platform(s) is/are applicable when browsing the Kotlin docs for the purposes of Android development?

Comment: The Android RunTime (ART) is a JVM, so yes. But "JVM" is sometimes colloquially used to mean JRT specifically and not Android, which is confusing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 do you have a source on ART being a JVM?  I've only heard it described as a 'managed runtime' without much detail on how specifically it's implemented.  Even the old Dalvik Virtual Machine was significantly different from the JVM, hence my confusion.

Comment: It's a VM that runs Java, so that's why I say it's a JVM. Maybe it doesn't strictly fit the definition, because there's an intermediate step of converting Java bytecode to dex bytecode. But the entire Java 7 standard library is available for use, which I think is what you're specifically asking about. You can additionally use a subset of Java 8 or Java 11 standard library if you enable Android desugaring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on Android Kotlin compiles into and is run on the JVM.  That's why it interacts with existing Java code/libraries and the Android framework (which is written in Java)

Comment: can you link a source?  I need citation before I can accept an answer :)

Comment: If you need a citation, I suggest googling rather than asking.  I'm not here to do all your research for you.